# Verify End user cert and SubCA fail OpenSSL

Tags: openssl, openvpn, ca

I'm doing a lab using 3 server:

RootCA --> SubCA --> OpenVPN.

I sign my SubCA using RootCA and verify it ok.

```
root@quanlm-rootca-openssl-lab:~/ca/root# openssl  verify -CAfile rootca.crt subca1/subca.crt 
subca1/subca.crt: OK
```

I also set X509V3 extensions in ca.conf in RootCA while sign the SubCA:

```
        X509v3 extensions:                                                              
            X509v3 Basic Constraints:                                                   
                CA:TRUE
```

Next, I use my subCA to sign OpenVPN server cert, when I verify the cert it fail, but when I verify the crl, it OK

```
root@quanlm-subca-openssl-lab:~/ca/subca# openssl verify -crl_check -CAfile vpnserver/vpnserver.crl.chain vpnserver/vpnserver.crt
vpnserver/vpnserver.crt: OK

root@quanlm-subca-openssl-lab:~/ca/subca# openssl verify -CAfile subca.crt 
vpnserver/vpnserver.crt
CN = SubCA, ST = Ha Noi, C = VN, emailAddress = rootca@actvn.edu.vn, O = Hoc Vien ky thuat mat ma, OU = Lop AT14
error 2 at 1 depth lookup: unable to get issuer certificate
error vpnserver/vpnserver.crt: verification failed
```

So can anyone help me with the problems? I cant run openVPN

```
Thu Nov  4 16:16:17 2021 us=279982 VERIFY ERROR: depth=1, error=unable to get issuer certificate: CN=SubCA, ST=Ha Noi, C=VN, emailAddress=rootca@actvn.edu.vn, O=Hoc Vien ky thuat mat ma, OU=Lop AT14
Thu Nov  4 16:16:17 2021 us=280016 OpenSSL: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
```

Comment: `openssl verify` by default only accepts a chain ending in a root. To verify the leaf against a sub(ordinate)CA cert only, add `-partial_chain` in 1.0.2 up. Your first form works because in `-CAfile` you supply the full _chain_ not only `subCA`; `-crl_check` is not needed. This is not a programming or development issue and thus offtopic.

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions:

1. Add the verbose flag for the openssl verify command (-verbose flag),
   to see the exact nature of the error
2. Store the RootCA cert in the ROOT-CA store of you machine - I think openssl tries to verify the full certificate chain, and can't verify SubCA
   (procedure varies, depending on the Linux distro you are using)

Comment: I use -verbose and I didn't show any more details

So I have to add rootCA in rootca store on SubCA server ?

Comment: Yes - that will be my best bet

Comment: Side comment -> would be better to write your suggestions in the comments section of the question.

Comment: `openssl verify` normally does try to verify the full chain, but when `-CAfile -CApath` are specified they are used _instead of_ the default store. Also this is offtopic.